# Connection between C# and database attributes

Tags: c#, database-connection

I would like to know whether my application will be vulnerable if before Publish and Release the project, someone sees the code below?

Any suggestions, is it good to leave it like this or there is a better way?

```
namespace ACCDataStore.Entity.Mapping
{
    public class UserMap : BaseEntityMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.ID);
            Map(x => x.Password);
            Map(x => x.Fullname);            
            Map(x => x.Organization);
            Map(x => x.Occupation);
            Map(x => x.Gender);
            Map(x => x.Password1);
            Map(x => x.Email);
            Map(x => x.EmailConfirmed);
            Map(x => x.Token);
            Map(x => x.TokenExpired);
            Map(x => x.TokenStart);
         }
    }

    public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual string Fullname { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Token { get; set; }
        public virtual string TokenStart { get; set; }
        public virtual bool TokenExpired { get; set; }
        public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public virtual string Organization { get; set; }
        public virtual string Occupation { get; set; }
        public virtual string Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password1 { get; set; }
        public virtual bool Enable { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }

        public virtual object GetJson()
        {
            return new
            {
                ID = this.ID,
                Password = this.Password,
                Fullname = this.Fullname,
                Email = this.Email,
                Token = this.Token,
                TokenStart = this.TokenStart,
                TokenExpired = this.TokenExpired,
                EmailConfirmed = this.EmailConfirmed,
                Organization = this.Organization,
                Occupation = this.Occupation,
                Gender = this.Gender,
                Password1 = this.Password1,
                Enable = this.Enable,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There will always be a better way. We, for example, don't store passwords in our database; we only store encrypted hashes. We also don't store password hashes with any contact information in the same table. Only a contact GUID and password in a table that we reference with linked data.

Comment: Are you asking if you should try to hide your database schema?

Comment: What do you mean that code is in app.config?

Comment: @Antony Securo this question doesn't make any sense to me - what is c# code doing inside the app.config?

Comment: I hide my database schema already, but because of the fact that our Professor will say: this strings and other attributes are vulnerable for the system and can mark down my project... that is why I am trying to find a way either to protect myself with good explanation or to redo my part which you can see above in the code.

Comment: p e p, it is not the question, it is up to you, the other people understood, check it again and think about.

Comment: @AnthonySecuro - I fully understand what you are asking, but what you are asking doesn't make any sense to me. And are you sure "the other people understood"? zackrspv's comment makes zero sense in the context of this question - s/he clearly didn't understand what you are asking. Blorgbeard asked what you are asking. Crowcoder asked the same thing I did - what is c# code doing in app.config? And you have 2 close votes for 'Unclear what you are asking'.  Let me rephrase my initial comment: putting c# code in the App.config makes no sense, therefore neither does this question.

Comment: There is not CSharp code in app.config, forget about app.config, just tell me if this way of connecting parameters in CSharp with DB is OK or not, for a security? I know that when I Publish the Csharp code all the controllers will be in a machine language transfered and no one can read the controllers but before that before publishing the code, what if someone see my code that is uploaded here? Is that bad is that good? How he can use it for bad things?